# How to output every second grouping in views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that outputs a list of nodes and their taxonomy terms. I use taxonomy field as grouping field. So I get:

```
Tax1 (article1, article2, article3 )
Tax2 (article4, article5, article6 )
Tax3 (article7, article8, article9 )
```

etc.

View makes markup for each group like this:

```
<div class="view-grouping">
<div class="view-grouping-header">
<div class="view-grouping-content">
<div class="views-row views-row-1"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3"></div>
</div></div>
```

Question:

How is it possible to output every second grouping?

I would like to have 2 columns with 2 views, first view would output every second grouping and second view would show other groupings.

I'm using Views 3.

Comment: What version of Views?

Comment: @Coleman views 3

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good use-case for a theme override.

If you click the "advanced" section in the view and click "Theme Information" at the bottom, you'll get a list of theme names. Click on "Style output" and copy the code, and paste it into a file in your theme folder with the most specific name possible (at the end of the list starting with "views-view-unformatted.tpl.php").

Not sure if there's a more elegant way to get a row count (it doesn't seem to be an available tpl variable) but you can DIY like so:

```
  <?php function count_this_view() {
    static $count = 0;
    return $count++;
  }?>
```

Then wrap your tpl in a conditional like

```
  <php if (count_this_view() % 2) :?>
```